# Angstrom Linux on Beagleboard boots into sleep mode

Tags: linux, authentication, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I'm running GNOME on Angstrom Linux on a Beagleboard, and have an issue when the device boots, i'm running the 2013-06-20 image from http://beagleboard.org/latest-images.

Power on, and the screen will display the Beagleboard logo, and continues to boot up. The screen goes black, but instead of loading onto the desktop, the screens (I've tried a few just to make sure) report no output from the device. If i move the mouse/press a key on the keyboard however it wakes up and displays the desktop.

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to prevent this 'sleep mode' (I doubt that's what it is, its just the best phrase I can think of describe this problem) from happening and just to boot up & display the desktop?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have fixed the issue I was having, firstly I'd suggest updating any outdated packages by opening a terminal and typing

```
opkg update
```

this should only take ~1 minute, aftewards type

```
opkg upgrade
```

This can take anywhere from ~10minutes to ~6 hours maybe even more, so be patient, just leave the device alone until it has finished.

then open the following file

```
nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and add the following

```
Section "ServerFlags"
   Option   "BlankTime"     "0"
   Option   "StandbyTime"   "0"
   Option   "SuspendTime"   "0"
   Option   "OffTime"       "0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Option       "DPMS"  
   Identifier   "Builtin Default Monitor"
EndSection
```

This should also disable any screensavers etc... which was also ideal for my requirements.

Reboot your device, and it should be good to go.